# How to convert list to dataframe which remain two columns considering duplicity in datasets?

Tags: r, list

I have a list in R as in the following example:

```
> exemplo
$`c("64735", "254528")`
[1] "703322"

$`100288287`
[1] "100426225"

$`391195`
[1] "707174" "706331"
```

I'm trying convert this list to dataframe remain two colums. I used this function:

```
> Reduce(rbind, Map(cbind, exemplo, gene = names(exemplo)))
                 gene                      
[1,] "703322"    "c(\"64735\", \"254528\")"
[2,] "100426225" "100288287"               
[3,] "707174"    "391195"                  
[4,] "706331"    "391195"
```

but I still have a problem in second column. Any Idea how it could be done.

Comment: It is not clear what you want to have happen to that errant term. Which one do you want to delete?

Comment: Sorry. I would something like this: `[1,] "703322"    "64735"     [2,] "703322"    "254528" [3,] .....`

Comment: Your `examplo` is very strange and not well builded. Try `do.call(rbind,Map(function(x,y) cbind(x=eval(parse(text=x)),y),names(exemplo),exemplo))`, even if it is not guarantee to work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We `stack` the 'exemplo' `list` to a 2-column `data.frame`, convert it to `data.table` (`setDT(..`), grouped by 'values', split the 'ind' column by characters other than number, `unlist`, and remove the rows where the output ('V1') is empty or blank.

```
library(data.table)
setDT(stack(exemplo))[, unlist(strsplit(as.character(ind), 
         '[^0-9]+')), by = values][V1!='']
#      values        V1
#1:    703322     64735
#2:    703322    254528
#3: 100426225 100288287
#4:    707174    391195
#5:    706331    391195
```

Comment: Great! Works. Thanks :-)